# Can Ring of Ma'rûf call in cards outside of MtG?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I’m building a completely casual deck with friends, and the the restrictions on [Ring of Ma'rûf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRing%5d%2b%5bof%5d%2b%5bMa%27r%c3%bbf%5d) aren’t entirely clear. Could I, for example, use Ring of Maruf to gradually bring in a YuGiOh card such as Exodia The Forbidden One. Could the Ring allow that?

Comment: In a casual game, you can do whatever you want... but... what are you going to do with Exordia once you have it in your hand?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can only get a *Magic: the Gathering* card.  The meaning of the word "card" is given explicitly in the rules:

> 108.2. When a rule or text on a card refers to a “card,” it means only a *Magic* card or an object represented by a *Magic* card.

Moreover, you can only get traditional *Magic* cards, so no Archenemy schemes, Planechase planes, etc:

> 108.2a Most *Magic* games use only *traditional Magic cards*, which measure approximately 2.5 inches (6.3 cm) by 3.5 inches (8.8 cm). Certain formats also use *nontraditional Magic cards*, oversized cards that may have different backs.
>
> 108.5. Nontraditional *Magic* cards can’t start the game in any zone other than the command zone (see rule 408). If an effect would bring a nontraditional *Magic* card into the game from outside the game, it doesn’t; that card remains outside the game.

So while you could choose your copy of [All in Good Time](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAll%20in%20Good%20Time%5d) with [Ring of Ma'rûf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRing%5d%2b%5bof%5d%2b%5bMa%27r%c3%bbf%5d), it would not be able to enter the game due to 108.5, and you effectively just waste your draw and exile the Ring for nothing.

Comment: In most competitive situation, they limit these pulls to cards in your sideboard and not your complete collection.   An example of this is Karn, the great creator which is  from War of the spark.